# Restringindo a seleção de linhas

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Gente, estou com um problema para fazer a seleção de linhas em um `datatable` que criei aqui. Ele me permite selecionar as duas primeiras linhas, contudo, as demais ele não deixa. Não faz nem o efeito do `hover`.

```
   <p:dataTable var="p" value="#{controleBean.portas}" paginator="true" 
        rows="30" id="dataTable" emptyMessage="Nenhuma Porta Cadastrada"
        paginatorPosition="bottom" selection="#{controleBean.portaSelecao}"
        selectionMode="single" rowKey="#{p.idPorta}" styleClass="datatable">

            <p:ajax event="rowSelect"
                updtate=":form:btnEditar :form:btnExcluir" />
            <p:ajax event="rowUnselect"
                updtate=":form:btnEditar :form:btnExcluir" />

            <p:column headerText="Número">
                <h:outputText value="#{p.numeroPorta}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Status">
                <h:outputText value="#{p.statusPorta}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Valor">
                <h:outputText value="#{p.valorPorta}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Reservatório">
                <h:outputText value="#{p.reservatorio.nomeReservatorio}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Bomba">
                <h:outputText value="#{p.bomba.nomeBomba}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Tipo">
                <h:outputText value="#{p.tipoPorta.nomeTipoPorta}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Placa">
                <h:outputText value="#{p.placa.nomePlaca}" />
            </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Print do datatable

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

ManagedBean

```
//imports
@ManagedBean(name="controleBean")
@SessionScoped 
public class ControleBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Bomba_Reservatorio bombaReservatorio;
    private Bomba bomba;
    private Historico historico;
    private Placa placa;
    private Porta porta;
    private Reservatorio reservatorio;
    private TipoPorta tipoPorta;

    private Bomba_Reservatorio bombaReservatorioSelecao;
    private Bomba bombaSelecao;
    private Historico historicoSelecao;
    private Placa placaSelecao;
    private Porta portaSelecao;
    private Reservatorio reservatorioSelecao;
    private TipoPorta tipoPortaSelecao;

    private List<Bomba_Reservatorio> bombasReservatorios;
    private List<Bomba> bombas;
    private List<Historico> historicos;
    private List<Placa> placas;
    private List<Porta> portas;
    private List<Reservatorio> reservatorios;
    private List<TipoPorta> tiposPortas;

    private Bomba_ReservatorioDAO bombaReservatorioDAO = new Bomba_ReservatorioDAO();
    private BombaDAO bombaDAO = new BombaDAO();
    private HistoricoDAO historicoDAO = new HistoricoDAO();
    private PlacaDAO placaDAO = new PlacaDAO();
    private PortaDAO portaDAO = new PortaDAO();
    private ReservatorioDAO reservatorioDAO = new ReservatorioDAO();
    private TipoPortaDAO tipoPortaDAO = new TipoPortaDAO();

    /***************************************/
    /*********** Métodos Próprios **********/
    /***************************************/   


    /***************************************/
    /************** Métodos DAO ************/
    /***************************************/

    public void novaBombaReservatorio() {
        bombaReservatorio = new Bomba_Reservatorio();
    }

    public void novaBomba() {
        bomba = new Bomba();
    }

    public void novoHistorico() {
        historico = new Historico();
    }

    public void novaPlaca() {
        placa = new Placa();
    }

    public void novaPorta() {
        porta = new Porta();
    }

    public void novoReservatorio() {
        reservatorio = new Reservatorio();
    }

    public void novoTipoPorta() {
        tipoPorta = new TipoPorta();
    }

    public void cadastrarBombaReservatorio() {
        bombaReservatorioDAO.salvar(bombaReservatorio);
    }

    public void cadastrarBomba() {
        bombaDAO.salvar(bomba);
    }

    public void cadastrarHistorico() {
        historicoDAO.salvar(historico);
    }

    public void cadastrarPlaca() {
        placaDAO.salvar(placa);
    }

    public void cadastrarPorta() {
        portaDAO.salvar(porta);
    }

    public void cadastrarReservatorio() {
        reservatorioDAO.salvar(reservatorio);
    }

    public void cadastrarTipoPorta() {
        tipoPortaDAO.salvar(tipoPorta);
    }

    public void excluirBombaReservatorio() {
        bombaReservatorioDAO.excluir(bombaReservatorioSelecao);
    }

    public void excluirBomba() {
        bombaDAO.excluir(bombaSelecao);
    }

    public void excluirHistorico() {
        historicoDAO.excluir(historicoSelecao);
    }

    public void excluirPlaca() {
        placaDAO.excluir(placaSelecao);
    }

    public void excluirPorta() {
        portaDAO.excluir(portaSelecao);
    }

    public void excluirReservatorio() {
        reservatorioDAO.excluir(reservatorioSelecao);
    }

    public void excluirTipoPorta() {
        tipoPortaDAO.excluir(tipoPortaSelecao);
    }

    /***************************************/
    /********** Getters e Setters **********/
    /***************************************/

    public Bomba_Reservatorio getBombaReservatorio() {
        return bombaReservatorio == null ? bombaReservatorio = new Bomba_Reservatorio() : bombaReservatorio;
    }

    public void setBombaReservatorio(Bomba_Reservatorio bombaReservatorio) {
        this.bombaReservatorio = bombaReservatorio;
    }

    public Bomba getBomba() {
        return bomba == null ? bomba = new Bomba() : bomba;
    }

    public void setBomba(Bomba bomba) {
        this.bomba = bomba;
    }

    public Historico getHistorico() {
        return historico == null ? historico = new Historico() : historico;
    }

    public void setHistorico(Historico historico) {
        this.historico = historico;
    }

    public Placa getPlaca() {
        return placa == null ? placa = new Placa() : placa;
    }

    public void setPlaca(Placa placa) {
        this.placa = placa;
    }

    public Porta getPorta() {
        return porta == null ? porta = new Porta() : porta;
    }

    public void setPorta(Porta porta) {
        this.porta = porta;
    }

    public Reservatorio getReservatorio() {
        return reservatorio == null ? reservatorio = new Reservatorio() : reservatorio;
    }

    public void setReservatorio(Reservatorio reservatorio) {
        this.reservatorio = reservatorio;
    }

    public TipoPorta getTipoPorta() {
        return tipoPorta == null ? tipoPorta = new TipoPorta() : tipoPorta;
    }

    public void setTipoPorta(TipoPorta tipoPorta) {
        this.tipoPorta = tipoPorta;
    }

    public Bomba_Reservatorio getBombaReservatorioSelecao() {
        return bombaReservatorioSelecao;
    }

    public void setBombaReservatorioSelecao(Bomba_Reservatorio bombaReservatorioSelecao) {
        this.bombaReservatorioSelecao = bombaReservatorioSelecao;
    }

    public Bomba getBombaSelecao() {
        return bombaSelecao;
    }

    public void setBombaSelecao(Bomba bombaSelecao) {
        this.bombaSelecao = bombaSelecao;
    }

    public Historico getHistoricoSelecao() {
        return historicoSelecao;
    }

    public void setHistoricoSelecao(Historico historicoSelecao) {
        this.historicoSelecao = historicoSelecao;
    }

    public Placa getPlacaSelecao() {
        return placaSelecao;
    }

    public void setPlacaSelecao(Placa placaSelecao) {
        this.placaSelecao = placaSelecao;
    }

    public Porta getPortaSelecao() {
        return portaSelecao;
    }

    public void setPortaSelecao(Porta portaSelecao) {
        this.portaSelecao = portaSelecao;
    }

    public Reservatorio getReservatorioSelecao() {
        return reservatorioSelecao;
    }

    public void setReservatorioSelecao(Reservatorio reservatorioSelecao) {
        this.reservatorioSelecao = reservatorioSelecao;
    }

    public TipoPorta getTipoPortaSelecao() {
        return tipoPortaSelecao;
    }

    public void setTipoPortaSelecao(TipoPorta tipoPortaSelecao) {
        this.tipoPortaSelecao = tipoPortaSelecao;
    }

    public List<Bomba_Reservatorio> getBombasReservatorios() {
        return bombasReservatorios = bombaReservatorioDAO.listar();
    }

    public List<Bomba> getBombas() {
        return bombas = bombaDAO.listar();
    }

    public List<Historico> getHistoricos() {
        return historicos = historicoDAO.listar();
    }

    public List<Placa> getPlacas() {
        return placas = placaDAO.listar();
    }

    public List<Porta> getPortas() {
        return portas = portaDAO.listar();
    }

    public List<Reservatorio> getReservatorios() {
        return reservatorios = reservatorioDAO.listar();
    }

    public List<TipoPorta> getTiposPortas() {
        return tiposPortas = tipoPortaDAO.listar();
    }

}
```

Se precisarem de mais algo, peçam que edito.

Obrigado.

Comment: Coloca um trecho do teu bean, talvez esclareça.

Comment: Amigo, a sintaxe do `update` não está correta no seu trecho. Onde tem `updtate` altere para `update`.

Comment: Lol, não havia reparado isso. kkk Já corrigi! Obrigado!

Comment: Resolveu o problema?

Comment: Infelizmente, não. :(

Comment: Essa tabela tá dentro de alguma outra `div`? Já inspecionou a área que ela tá ocupando? Testou em quais browser's?

Comment: Sim, ela está. Vou Inspecionar agora. Firefox e Chrome.

Comment: Velho, que viagem. Quando ativo o inspetor, consigo selecionar as linhas.

Comment: Verifique se não é algum conflito de css ou algo do tipo.

Comment: Não havia conflitos. :/

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30585/discussion-between-weslley-tavares-and-hdeiro).